# R: Vectorize Finite Difference Equations

Tags: r, fortran95

I'm trying to move some Fortran code to R for finite differences related to chemical kinetics.

Sample Fortran loop:

```
DOUBLE PRECISION, DIMENSION (2000,2) :: data=0.0
DOUBLE PRECISION :: k1=5.0, k2=20.0, dt=0.0005
DO i=2, 2000
  data(i,1) = data(i-1,1) + data(i-1,1)*(-k1)*dt
  data(i,2) = data(i-1,2) + ( data(i-1,1)*k1*dt - data(i-1,2)*k2*dt )
  ...
END DO
```

The analogous R code:

```
k1=5
k2=20
dt=0.0005
data=data.frame(cbind(c(500,rep(0,1999)),rep(0,2000)))
a.fun=function(y){
     y2=y-k1*y*dt
     return(y2)
 }
apply(data,2,a.fun)
```

This overwrites my first value in the dataframe and leaves zeros elsewhere. I'd like to run this vectorized and not using a for loop since they are *so* slow in R. Also, my function only calculates the first column so far. I can't get the second column working until I get the syntax right on the first.

Comment: Two comments:  1:  If this is working in Fortran, why not use that?  2:  Your code returns an error: `Error in FUN(newX[, i], ...) : object 'k1' not found1`

Comment: Thank you for catching the error. I've edited the code. I know that my function is incomplete so far. What I'm stuck on right now is how to translate the references to the previous iteration. `data[1,2]=data[1,1]-data[1,1]*k1*dt` 
Does that make sense?

Also Fortran is handy on Linux, but not as much for Windows.

Comment: Well, I can't tell what you want, since `data` has two columns, and column 2 is all zeros, as can be seen by `any(data$X2 != 0)`.  More comments:  Your R code doesn't define `k1` or `dt`.  Also, don't use `data` or `dt` as variable names.  These are names of R functions.

Comment: What are your initial values of data(1,1) and data(1,2) ?

Comment: I haven't gotten to figuring out the second column yet since it depends on the first column, which I can't get working. I added the k1 and dt variables. `data[1,]= 500  0`.

Comment: What is being modeled here is that some chemical in `data[,1]` is being consumed to produce a chemical in `data[,2]`. The example here is more simple than what I need to do. As `data[,2]` is produced, it is also consumed to make a chemical in a third column (not represented here).

Comment: I think the fortran code cannot be solved without knowing the initial value of `data(1,2)`. Since the loop start from `2:2000` you need to know value at `i=1` for both `data(1,1)` and `data(1,2)`. I assumed both as `500` for the initial condition and posted the answer.

Comment: The Fortran code definitely runs. The initial value of `data[1,2]` is 0. I appreciate the post but it's not what I'm looking to do.

Comment: The premise of the question is flawed. Ancient claims regarding such are not credible.  `for`-loops are not slower than `apply` methods. Furthermore they are needed fo this purpose, so attempting to use apply is just wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its not necessarily true that R is bad at loops.  It very much depends on what you are doing.  Using `k1`, `k2`, `dt` and `data` from the question (i.e. the four lines beginning with `k1=5`) and formulating the problem in terms of an iterated matrix, the loop in the last line below returns nearly instantaneously on my PC:

```
z <- as.matrix(data)
m <- matrix(c(1-k1*dt, k1*dt, 0, 1-k2*dt), 2)

for(i in 2:nrow(z)) z[i, ] <- m %*% z[i-1, ]
```

(You could also try storing the vectors in columns of z rather than rows since R stores matrices by column.)

Here is the first bit of the result:

```
> head(z)
           X1       X2
[1,] 500.0000 0.000000
[2,] 498.7500 1.250000
[3,] 497.5031 2.484375
[4,] 496.2594 3.703289
[5,] 495.0187 4.906905
[6,] 493.7812 6.095382
```

Comment: Could you provide `head(z)`? I'm getting `z[1,]= 500 0` and `z[2,]= 0 0`.

Comment: Also I don't quite follow the list in your second code line. Could you please elaborate a little? There are 4 items in `m` but only 2 columns in `z`.

Comment: `m` is 2x2 and `z[i-1,]` is a vector of length 2 (that can be regarded as 2x1 for purposes of matrix multiplication) so the matrix product is 2x1  and we assign that to `z[i,]` which is also of length 2. I have added the `head` output and added discussion of which lines of the question need to be entered.

Answer (score 1):

May be this can help.

I think you need to have the initial condition for `data[1,2]`. I assumed both `data[1,1]` as 500 and `data[1,2` as 0 at the initial condition.

The code goes like this:

```
> ## Define two vectors x and y
> x <- seq(from=0,length=2000,by=0)
> y <- seq(from=0,length=2000,by=0)
> 
> ## Constants
> k1 = 5.0
> dt = 0.0005
> k2 = 20.0
> 
> ## Initialize x[1]=500 and y[1]=0
> x[1]=500
> y[1] = 0
> 
> for (i in 2:2000){
+   x[i]=x[i-1]+x[i-1]*-k1*dt
+   y[i] = y[i-1]+x[i-1]*k1*dt-y[i-1]*k2*dt
+ }
> 
> finaldata <- data.frame(x,y)
> head(finaldata)
         x        y
1 500.0000 0.000000
2 498.7500 1.250000
3 497.5031 2.484375
4 496.2594 3.703289
5 495.0187 4.906905
6 493.7812 6.095382
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: That translates the Fortran code directly into R using the same loop structure and gets the numbers to work, but it scales quite poorly because R is bad at calculating quickly **for** loops. I'm looking to use *apply() with an appropriate function definition.

Comment: `for` isn't really much worse than `apply`.  They're both loops.  And you want to loop over rows, with interactions between columns.  `apply` isn't apt for that job.

Comment: I think using apply will become more complicated here.

Comment: I give up. I tried to use `apply` but it doesn't seem to do the job. That is the best I came up with. Hope somebody comes up with the apply function for you. Good luck.

Comment: Matthew, do you have any idea what tool may be more appropriate? I read through an R journal article about the deSolve package but I'm in way over my head. I don't have that firm a grasp of DE's.

Comment: Jdbaba, thanks for your effort. I think that the issue is in the `a.fun` function not doing something that it should.

Comment: @user28505 Sorry, I have never used R for difference equations.  About your latest comment, `a.fun` can't do what you want unless you are modifying global data within the function -- in which case, you're much better off using a `for` loop.

Comment: It scales linearly; what is the problem with that?